# Как создать роль после другой?

Tags: javascript, discord

Нужно создать роль, которая по списку будет находиться после определённой роли

discord.js

Answer (score 2):

Можно получить роль на сервере, узнать ее позицию и прибавить или отнять от нее единицу, после чего задать свойство position при создании роли.

Как-то так:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', `${client.user.username} is online on ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers!`);
});

let prefix = '!';

client.on('message', async (message) => {
    let targetRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('SOMEROLEID');
    if (!targetRole) return console.log(`Не могу найти роль`);
    let targetPosition = targetRole.calculatedPosition + 1; //+1 upper, -1 down
    await message.guild.roles.create('My role', {
        position: targetPosition,
    });
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```